# lmer: poly of time as fixed effect but factorized time as random slope?

Tags: r, random, lme4, polynomials

In my mixed-effects model (lmer from lme4) I have a four-way interaction as a fixed effect including

1. a cubic polynomial of time (training sessions)
2. Age
3. Food dosis (half of the animals having 0 gr, whereas the rest varying from 1 until 7 gr)
4. Condition (4 levels).

My question concerns the issue that a polynomial as random slope has been discussed as over-complexifying the model and my model also does not converge when using poly in my random effects. When plotting the interaction and dichotomizing food and age for visualisation of my data,
I see that for the animals with food, the polynomial course is apparent across time for all conditions in a similar pattern, whereas no food intake was associated with a linear trend.

Two ideas about alternatives of using poly as a random slope:

alternative 1: just use time as a linear effect as a random slope, while keeping the polynomial time effect as a main effect

alternative 2: factorize time into lets say weeks (3 weeks in total),
 because the polynomial effect for the animals with food followed a weekly pattern.

Comment on 2: of course this argumentation is somewhat arbitrary, therefore I was wondering if I could get some advice on a better solution.

Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: I'm very skeptical of any polynomial above second order in regression. Is there a reason from scientific theory for using a third order polynomial? If not, you should probably look into using a GAM. Anyway, I'm having trouble imagining how you would interpret the models from your two alternatives. If you can't explain that, you shouldn't use them.

Comment: thanks for your reply. There is scientific evidence that a third order polynomial is justified. But even if I had a quadratic effect, my problem would still persist. I gave an explanation for alternative 2, I am unhappy with it, so I was asking for help

Comment: Obviously, I don't have the necessary knowledge of the scientific background. All I can say is that the fixed effects part of your model already appears to be obviously over-parameterized unless you have a truly massive amount of data. I would start with trying to remove higher order interactions. Then with a much simpler fixed part of the model I would try adding random slopes and an auto-correlation structure (see the nlme package for the latter).

Comment: we've got 90 000 observations in total; our data is quite large with respect to amount of subjects and other variables. We calculated a seperate model for each of the four conditions, so we dopped the effect out of the four-way interaction - and our results looked quite similar, so the overparametrization does not bias the results to this extend.